Unexpected record triggered Scheduled path behavior
We have a simple Record Triggered Flow (After create only with a criteria) with a scheduled path which is doing an external service call with a batch size 1 (below).

Scheduled path is used because external API needs to receive 1 record at a time, and just Async path doesn't support setting the batch size.
But when running it's scheduling the Flow much later than it's supposed to be,
For example the Task is created at 28/6/2024, 1:16 pm, but scheduled run is at 28/6/2024, 1:31 pm. (below).

I wonder if this is due to resource availability? Any explanation for this behaviour with a SF reference, and suggestions for better workarounds to run the external callout (invocable) without this delay and without needing Apex would be appreciated.

This is not unexpected, scheduling is acquiring and consuming scarce system resources in a multi-tenant system. You could try setting the offset to -1 minutes but still no guarantees

Thanks @cropredy, My worry is sometimes this is 50 mins, 1h+ late. and we're having the same issue with Lead records as well causing them to be blocked and cannot be converted while in a time based flow interval. I'll give a try on your suggestion and report back here if it helps. cheers!

You'll most likely get better results with using invocable apex that immediately does a future or queueable. I've never had a future/queueable delay for more than mere seconds
